# Should I install the bcmwl-kernel-source or broadcom-sta-* packages for my Broadcom 4352 wi-fi adapter?

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, source, dkms

Should I install the bcmwl-kernel-source or broadcom-sta-* packages for my Broadcom 4352 wi-fi adaper? I currently have the bcmwl-kernel-source package installed and it works but if the broadcom-sta-* is a better solution I would like to see if there's a difference.

This is not a question about how to install the driver which this supposedly is a duplcate of, but rather which of the two Broadcom drivers that currently are available for Ubuntu I should use. The older driver works, but I would like to try the newer one it works better

Comment: Please reopen the question. `broadcom-sta-dkms` is a newer proprietary driver and it solves some issues. It is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: I did search and did not find an answer here. I got one now though :)

Comment: I tried to install the newer driver, but when I rebooted the mouse was unresponsive and I did not have wi-fi at all. I'm not sure how to switch from one to the other driver. Do I have to uninstall bcmwl-kernel-source package, reboot and install broadcom-sta-dkms?

Comment: You need to uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` first.

Comment: But I am not sure that `wl` is correct for your adapter.

Comment: So the newer driver isn't right for all 4352 Wi-Fi adapters? And after I remove they kernel:source package I need to reboot. I guess I should be playing with this while on a wired connection :-)

Comment: I do not know which driver is correct. You can find out if you read the duplicate link.

Comment: I had to remove bcmwl-kernel-source. Make sure all packages I need was cached sinceI would not have network. The dkms driver did not work, but broadcom-sta-source did. I installed it rebooted and enabled it with the "Additional Drivers" interface. My question and solution is not a duplicate but answers how to switch between the three driver options for this broadcom wi-fi adapter.